# Que significa este error en React Native?

Tags: react-native

Estoy usando la libreria React-Native-Image-Picker, al tratar de probarla tuve el siguiente mensaje de error, que significa con exactitud?

Verifique si la libreria requiere permisos pero por lo visto no, ya que tan solo requiero el acceso a imagenes de la galeria. Agradecido de antemano.

```js
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity, Platform, PermissionsAndroid } from 'react-native'
import React from 'react'
import { launchCamera, launchImageLibrary } from 'react-native-image-picker'
const App = () => {
  const elegirImagen = (type) => {
    let opciones = {
      mediaType: type,
      maxWidth: 300,
      maxHeight: 550,
      quality: 1,
    };

    launchImageLibrary(opciones, (response) => {
      console.log('Response = ', response);

      if (response.didCancel) {
        alert('Imagen cancelada');
        return;
      }
      else if (response.errorCode == 'permission') {
        alert('Permisos no otorgados?');
        return;
      } else if (response.errorCode == 'others') {
        alert(response.errorMessage);
        return;
      }
      console.log('base64 -> ', response.assets.base64);
      console.log('uri -> ', response.assets.uri);
      console.log('fileName -> ', response.assets.fileName);
    });
  }


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={elegirImagen('photo')}>
        <Text>Selecciona una imagen de tu galeria</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  )
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Al parecer el problema es porque estas tratando de usar un objeto cuando en realidad este objeto es nulo. Y si pruebas con _await_ como en [este ejemplo](https://github.com/react-native-image-picker/react-native-image-picker)?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera acabo de probar tu sugerencia, aun así no funciona, sigue mostrándome el mismo error 'null', aun no comprendo a que se debe el error.

Comment: assets siempre retorna un array pero también tienes que validar algo así if (response.assets) { const image = response.assets[0]; }

Comment: también estas accediendo a response.assets.base64 y te hace falta en opciones agregar el valor includeBase64: true,